# Alias for git cloning with user name and email set locally?

Tags: git, github

I really want to set a different user.name and user.email in Git for work and open source contributions, while still working from the same machine.

Is it possible to make a Git Alias for cloning into a repo and defining the local gitconfig right away?

Comment: Another take on this, instead of having separate instances of the same repo on the machine  (each having their appropriate --local user.name/user.email) which you need to sync with each other is to have some agent on your machine that periodically (and upon wakeup) figures out if you are at work or home and then does the git config --local for you.

Comment: For sure :) I personally don't have the problem of having repos which are both work and pleasure though. So i can pretty much segregate each repo into it's own permanent role, luckily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use, put this in your global .gitconfig file.

A working alias for cloning into a repo and configuring the .git/config to a specific name and email:

```
[alias]
oclone = !git clone $1 && cd $(basename $1 .git) && git config user.name myname && git config user.email my@mail.com
```

the ! escapes the alias into it's own shell, and allows us to execute multiple git-commands  and other terminal commands like basename in sequence.

$1 is the first argument passed in after the command (your repo to clone from), like you would expect.

It is used exactly like a normal git clone command:

```
git oclone git@github.com:myuser/myrepo.git
```